# How is fixpoint of type exponentiation implemented?

Tags: implementation, types, functions

Fixpoint of type addition or type multiplication is no big deal. You just need to store data in heap. Haskell does this well for lists for example:

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Yet Haskell also permits fixpoint of type exponentiation. I'll take the following example:

```
newtype FixPower = FixPower {appFixPower :: FixPower -> Bool}
```

Some examples of values of this type include:

```
example1 = FixPower (\_ -> False)
exmaple2 = FixPower (\_ -> True)
example3 = FixPower (`appFixPower` example1)
example4 = FixPower (`appFixPower` example4)
example5 = FixPower (not . `appFixPower` example5)
example6 = FixPower (join appFixPower)
```

I cannot even grasp how these values are stored in hardware. I don't see how to imitate this type in (relatively) low-level languages such as C. Does this involve some unsafe casting of function pointers? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Just because C has no spelling for it doesn’t mean it can’t exist. Function pointers are all the same in the hardware.

Comment: OP posted a similar question on StackOverflow 2 years ago, if that's interesting to anyone: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68735804

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In GHC Haskell:

- `FixPower` has kind `Type`
- `Type` is a synonym of `TYPE LiftedRep`
- `LiftedRep` is a synonym of `'BoxedRep 'Lifted`
- `BoxedRep` indicates that this object is represented by a pointer
- `Lifted` indicates that the pointer may be a lazy computation, not just a value
- `(->)` is a synonym of `FUN`
- `FUN` has kind `forall r1 r2. TYPE r1 -> TYPE r2 -> Type`
- In this case, `r1` and `r2` are both instantiated to `LiftedRep` as well

Therefore, `FixPower` is a closure thunk pointer, whose underlying function pointer takes a pointer of the same description, and returns a `Bool` thunk pointer.

If we ignore laziness and closures, and just focus on the essence of the function itself, a translation to C is surprisingly direct:

```
typedef struct FixPower {
  bool (*app)(struct FixPower);
} FixPower;
```

```
// FixPower (const False)
bool const_false(FixPower fp) { return false; }
FixPower example_false = (FixPower){ .app = &const_false };
```

```
// FixPower (const True)
bool const_true(FixPower fp) { return true; }
FixPower example_true = { const_true };
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  bool result = example_true.app(example_false);
  printf("%s\n", result ? "true" : "false");
  return 0;
}
```

> Does this involve some unsafe casting of function pointers?

No, you do need a `struct` in order to be able to express a self-referential type definition in C, just as you need a `newtype` in Haskell. But C has no problem with it, as long as the type is finite in size—which is so, if the self-reference goes through an indirection, as in a more familiar case like a linked list:

```
struct Node {
  int value;
  struct Node *next;
};
```

In `FixPower`, the pointer just happens to be a *function* pointer, rather than a *data* pointer. Note that we can pass `struct FixPower` *by value* to the function call, since it’s just a function pointer, which has a fixed and finite size. This is really the essence of representation-hiding: `sizeof(T *)` is independent of `sizeof(T)`.

Another way of thinking of this type, and [hyperfunctions](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2021-03-14-hyperfunctions.html) more generally, is as a chain of cooperatively scheduled coroutines, navigating over a tree of possible computations.

A `FixPower` value represents a label for a computation, which is passed a “next routine” label by its caller. It can *return* a result back up the tree to its caller—in this case just a `Bool`, but in general it could be any value. Before the routine returns, it has the chance to *yield* down the tree to the next routine, as many times as it likes. And each time it yields, it’s allowed to decide which routine will be “next” for that subtree.